# Query items by timestamp in Logstash

Tags: http, curl, elasticsearch, logstash

So I want to get all events since a certain time, for example since `"2017-03-02T21:56:53.033Z"`.

I made a `runtime_timestamp` field that just copies the `@timestamp` field, because I am parsing this data into C# and `@` symbols don't play nice in there.

Here is my Logstash filter for that, which DOES work. I know this for a fact.

```
 filter {
    mutate {
            add_field => ["runtime_timestamp", "%{@timestamp}"]

    }
}
```

Here is the what I have now, that does not work.

```
{
 "query": {
 "range": {
  "runtime_timestamp": 
    "2017-03-02T21:56:53.033Z"
},
"_source": {
"includes": [
  "runtime_timestamp",
  "id_orig_p",
  "id_orig_p",
  "id_orig_h",
  "conn_state",
  "id_resp_h",
  "id_resp_p",
  "service",
  "proto",
  "tags"
]
},
"sort": [
{
  "@timestamp": {
    "order": "desc"
  }
}
]
}
```

Now, I get the following error from this query.

```
 {
  "error" : {
  "root_cause" : [
  {
    "type" : "parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "[range] query does not support [runtime_timestamp]",
    "line" : 5,
    "col" : 9
  }
  ],
   "type" : "parsing_exception",
   "reason" : "[range] query does not support [runtime_timestamp]",
   "line" : 5,
   "col" : 9
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

I tried this query also with `timestamp` in place of `runtime_timestamp`, and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your range query is malformed. Try this instead (gte means greater-than-or-equal):

```
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "runtime_timestamp" : {
                "gte": "2017-03-02T21:56:53.033Z", 
            }
        }
    }
}
```